# button and bundle with android to change text, application crash

Tags: android, button, textbox, crash, bundle

```
        buttCalc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        EditText val1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        EditText val2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit2);
        EditText risultato = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.risultato);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Valore2", val2.getText().toString());
        risultato.setText(bundle.getString("Valore2"));
```

hello guys, when i click that button, my app crash in the vm, i would like to:
1 click button
2 risultato textbox = val2 text

thank you in first

Comment: to set text why do you need bundle? `risultato.setText(val2.getText().toString())` is enough

Comment: have you done findviewbyid for button.

Comment: You have some ID problem, You code is working fine.

Comment: Some more code+ logcat is neededd..

Comment: @kalyanpvs i don't think it edittext intialization in button click would cause NPE. and setText can take null http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/TextView.java#TextView.setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: @Raghunandan because i'm trying to write something like a calculator, learning how to programming android apps.

Comment: @Brontok java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Comment: @myself to do that why do you need bundle? you can get and set text without bundle

Comment: @Raghunandan yes it will not cause NPE.just now checked..

Comment: @myself which one's of the 3 editexts is a textview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

What you have is a text view but you are casting to edittext. So change your initialization

If you have a textview in xml with id `textView1` initialize as below

```
   TextView tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
```

You get ClassCastException bcoz you are casting textview to edittext

Also initialize your views outside onClick

Comment: @myself you are welcome and initialize views outside onClick no need to initialize everytime button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

In your xml layout one of the below id's

```
(R.id.edit1);
(R.id.edit2);
(R.id.risultato);
```

belongs to a Textview.